# Can I make NPCs on Minecraft: Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking to see if there is a way to make an NPC on Minecraft: Java Edition

For those of you who don't know what NPCs are, they are these fellows that you can speak to in Bedrock Edition:

[image: NPC]

You can add your own dialogue to the text box, and even add custom buttons that can make something happen when clicked.

How would I get something like this on Minecraft: Java Edition? Would it be through commands? Or would third-party mods/plugins need to become involved?

Comment: Whoever voted to close im not exactly sure how he could be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated the version of Minecraft that you are playing, so not sure if this will work on your version, but try [Citizens](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/citizens.13811/). It's unfortunately not free, but it does exactly what you're looking for—it has the ability to create NPCs with just right click dialogues to performing different commands.

This is a description of features in brief from the website itself:

```
  Basic NPCs - right click messages, items, looking around, waypoints, and 
  much more.
  Lots of commands to customise your NPCs
  Extensive developer API allowing scriptable NPCs through plugins such as 
  Denizen.
  Vault-compatible
```

If you're looking for something free, try [this other NPC plugin](https://forums.spongepowered.org/t/snowman-npcs-v3-0-0-easiest-and-best-npc-plugin/18273)
According to its website, it has the following features:

```
Drag-and-drop installation
No configuration required
Easy-to-use NPC menu
Many NPC Options
NPC Interaction system:
Player Commands
Console Commands
Messages
Delays
Pauses
Conditions
Cooldowns
Choices
Goto’s
bStats 537 Metrics
PlaceholderAPI 863 integration (optional but recommended)
```

Comment: That's certainly an improvement over before. A few brushup like I just did would be nice.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 yes, it sure did make it a lot better, thanks I will keep these kind of changes in mind from next time.

Comment: At the time of writing this comment Citizens is free, they just encourage purchasing it.

Answer (score -3):

To create NPCs, open your inventory (type E) and add a Spawn Egg to your inventory. Place the Spawn Egg to create an NPC. To program an NPC, right click the NPC to bring up the customize screen. but since there is Np spawn egg, it's tough to say.

Comment: There is no NPC spawn egg in Minecraft: Java Edition.

Comment: This is for education edition

Comment: @Penguin he *is* the asker, lol.

Comment: i  wish, then i wouldnt of lost all  my rep

Comment: @mindstormsboi oops i seem to have atted the wrong person! Meant to do the answerer